# Automatically switch between household power and inverter when power is lost

Tags: relay, inverter

I’m setting up a backup system for my home’s sump pump. Rather than deal with the installation/maintenance of a separate backup pump I’ve decided to go with an inverter & 12 V battery setup. My sump pump claims 9 A draw, so I purchased a 2000 W inverter and a battery.

What I didn’t realize is that the inverter is only for providing constant power, but does not switch between power sources. The inverter has a standard AC outlet on it for plugging in a load. What I think I’m looking for is a relay that switches between two 120 V power sources and sends the power to a single load. I’ve tried searching, but I feel like I might be missing the right terms to narrow down to what I’m looking for. Any tips on finding a relay like this? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Instead of inverter, look for Standby Power Supply or Uninterruptible Power Supply...

Comment: Or get a beefy enough charger to charge the batteries and run the pump via the inverter.  (in essence, a DIY double conversion UPS)

Comment: This is one case where a bad installation can cause harm to other people by back feeding power to the supply. Because of this some areas demand that installation of a transfer switch (which is what this is) is done by a a licensed electrician.  You might want to check your local codes.

Comment: Forgot to mention it’s an inverter/charger, so it’s going to charge the batter while not in use.

Answer (score 5):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjoimS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Automatic transfer circuit.*

Figure 1 shows one way of doing the job.

- RLY1 needs to be a contactor (heavy-duty relay).
- Coil voltage = 120 V or 240 V AC, depending on your supply.
- Contact rating 10 A inductive or motor start rated at the AC voltage you are switching.
- Contact arrangement: 2-pole, changeover.

When mains power is lost (as shown in the schematic) power will be supplied from the inverter. When power is restored the relay will energise and power the pump from the mains.

Normal safety precautions apply. Install in box that requires tools or key to open. Gland all cables to prevent chaffing. Add a fuse to cut supply to the coil in the event of a solenoid fault. It may prevent a fire.

Comment: I am wondering if the unavoidable phase shift between the mains and the inverter can cause any problems to the pump.

Comment: Very good point and it had completely slipped my mind. I'd be more worried about the inverter on mains failure as switching on to the pump when running 180° out of phase would cause large surge currents. Switching back to mains would have the same problem but the mains should handle it provided the circuit breaker is slow enough. This complicates things! We need some way to prevent inverter startup until the pump stops.

Comment: A UPS doesn't have that problem does it?

Comment: It shouldn't. A good one would sync with the mains and transfer without much of a bump.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a *power transfer switch* which serve that very purpose you are seeking to resolve.

Most inverter chargers already have them built in.  If yours does not, they can be obtained on-line from numerous sources.

Answer (score 1):

A contactor is to be used to switch the pump from the grid supply to the back-up inverter when the grid supply fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would want to buy pump century sec 822ps and battery, or pump spy with battery. Obv bit late for that, but this solution is what you would want from the start.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Friendly tip: you might want to expand upon your answer, and refrain from abbreviations (abbrev's) and short hand - just to make your post more legible (especially for non-native speakers)